# Изменение скидки товары с помощью REST API

Tags: api, rest, битрикс24

использую метод crm.deal.productrows.set. Когда добавляю параметр id, и в параметр rows вношу значения такие как DISCOUNT_SUM, PRODUCT_ID - в сделке происходит следующее: Товар удаляется, Товар Добавляется (Тот же самый) и цену проставляет ту, что указана в DISCOUNT_SUM
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте указать все данные товара.
Раньше был нюанс, что если передавались не все параметры товарной позиции, то результат отличался от ожидаемого.
Примерно так:

[image: Обновление товарных позиций в сделках]